# InterruptedException on .stop() call of StreamingContext without stopping SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am having some trouble with stopping a streaming context after a condition has been met inside a `foreachRDD`. Any time the `scc.stop()` inside function `foo` is executed, I get an Interrupted error.

Simplified Code:

```
def main(){
    var sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("appname").setMaster("local"))
    foo(123,sc)
    //foo(312,sc) can I call foo again here?
    sc.stop()
}


def foo(param1: Integer, sc: SparkContext){
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
    val res = 0
    //dummy data, but actual datatypes (but is not relevant to the error I get in this code)
    val inputData: mutable.Queue[RDD[Int]] = mutable.Queue()
    val inputStream: InputDStream[Int] = ssc.queueStream(inputData)
    inputData += sc.makeRDD(List(1, 2))
    val rdds_list=some_other_fn(inputstream,param1) //returns DStream
    rdds_list.foreachRDD((rdd) => {
        def foo1(rdd: RDD[<some_type_2>]) = {
            if (condition1) {
                println("condition satisfied!") //prints correctly
                res = do_stuff(rdd) //executes correctly
                println("result: " + res) //executes correctly (and output is as intended)
            }else{
                  println("stopping streaming context!")
                  ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = false) //error occurs here
            }
        }
        foo(rdd)
     })
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
    res
}
```

Error log:

```
**condition satisfied!
result: 124124**
stopping streaming context!
[error] (pool-11-thread-1) java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1155)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1252)
        at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1326)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus.stop(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler.stop(JobScheduler.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.stop(StreamingContext.scala:573)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.stop(StreamingContext.scala:555)
        at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main$$anonfun$testClustering$1.foo$1(Main.scala:315)
        at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main$$anonfun$testClustering$1.apply(Main.scala:318)
        at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main$$anonfun$testClustering$1.apply(Main.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(DStream.scala:534)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:40)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:176)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried using `ssc.stop(stopSparkContext = true, stopGracefully = true)` but I get this:

```
WARN  scheduler.JobGenerator -
Timed out while stopping the job generator (timeout = 10000)
```

after `foo` is called and the program just gets stuck (i.e it does not complete and I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it).

Is this the correct way to stop a streaming context? Also, if I wanted to call `foo` multiple times, should I make any changes? I understand that there should only be one spark context in an application that's why I am trying to re-use them or should I close the `SparkContext` by setting `stopSparkContext` as `true`?

My environment:

- sbt v1.0
- Scala 2.10.5
- Spark 1.3.1

Edit: Looked at other similar questions, tried all their answers - still no luck! :(

Answer (score 0):

It shows that while the spark driver was waiting for the job to finish, you are closing StreamingContext inside the `rdd_list` which is being handled by the very StreamingContext. This should be closed separately.
And the contexts shouldn't be created and closed with such frequency.

What i would recommend is to do the following...

Initiate and pass `StreamingContext` from `main()` to `foo(...)`

Which will make foo

`def foo(param1: Integer, ssc: StreamingContext)`

To safely close both of the contexts for a streaming application would be like...

```
sys.ShutdownHookThread {
//Executes when shutdown signal is received by the app
      log.info("Gracefully stopping Spark Context")
      sc.stop()
      ssc.stop(true, true)
      log.info("Application stopped")
}
```

But if you need to close with programmaticly logic, close `StreamingContext` with `SparkContext`.

Which will make your `main()` look like

```
def main(){
    var sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("appname").setMaster("local"))
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
    sys.ShutdownHookThread {
    //Executes when shutdown signal is received by the app
        log.info("Gracefully stopping Spark Context")
        sc.stop()
        ssc.stop(true, true)
        log.info("Application stopped")
    }
    foo(123,ssc)
    sc.stop()
    ssc.stop
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ahab! But doesn't the `ShutdownHookThread` work only for external shutdown signals such as `ctrl+c`? What I wanted is a proper (error free) way to close `ssc` and exit from `foreachRDD` after the `condition1` has failed inside `foo1`. I will anyways try your method and let you know the results!

Comment: Correct, or some application failure, the context would be safely closed and cleaned up. I feel you, but there is a need for keeping these two operations separately.